# Why does msgrcv return Identifier removed?

Tags: linux, ipc, message-queue, sysv-ipc

I'm learning IPCS and I try to send a message from a client to a server which will multiply it by 2 and send it back to the client using `ftok`, `msgget`, `msgrcv`, `msgsnd` and `msgctl` services of libc/linux.
Here is my code:

**ex1.h**

```
#ifndef EX1_H
#define EX1_H

#define ID 2
#define PATH "./client.c"
struct msgbuf{
  long mtype;
  int mvalue;
} message, retour;
key_t cle;
int mes_id;
#endif
```

**serveur.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include "ex1.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv){
  if((cle=ftok(PATH,ID)) == (key_t)-1){
    perror("Erreur lors de la création de la clé ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if((mes_id = msgget(cle,IPC_CREAT | 0660 | IPC_EXCL)) == -1){
    perror("Erreur dans la création de la file de message ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  message.mtype = 1;
  if((msgrcv(mes_id, &message, sizeof(message), 1, 0)) == -1){
    perror("Erreur lors de la récéption du message ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("Je suis le serveur et j'ai reçu %d.\n",message.mvalue);
  printf("J'effectue ma multiplication par 2 et renvoie le résultat.\n");
  retour.mtype = 3;
  retour.mvalue = message.mvalue * 2;
  if((msgsnd(mes_id, &retour, sizeof(retour), 0)) == -1){
    perror("Erreur lors de l'envoi du résultat ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  sleep(1);
  msgctl(mes_id,IPC_RMID, NULL);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include "ex1.h"
#include <unistd.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv){
  if((cle=ftok(PATH, ID)) == (key_t)-1){
    perror("Erreur lors de la création de la clé ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if((mes_id = msgget(cle, 0660 | IPC_EXCL)) == -1){
    perror("Erreur lors de la récupération du numéro de la file ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  message.mtype = 1;
  message.mvalue = 4;
  if((msgsnd(mes_id, &message, sizeof(message), 0)) == -1){
    perror("Erreur lors de l'envoi du message ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  retour.mtype = 3;
  sleep(2);
  if((msgrcv(mes_id, &retour, sizeof(retour), 3, 0)) == -1){
    perror("Erreur lors de la récéption du résultat ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("Je suis le client et j'ai reçu %d\n", retour.mvalue);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Due to line 23/24, I get `Invalid argument` (**EINVAL**) or `Identifier removed` (**EIDRM**) errors,
but I don't understand what is the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

**"size" parameter of *msgsnd()/msgrcv()***

*msgsnd()* and *msgrcv()* receive the size of the data part of the message (the *type* field is not included). This should be used like this:

```
struct msgbuf{
  long mtype;
  int mvalue;
} message, retour;
[...]
msgrcv(mes_id, &retour, sizeof(retour.mvalue), 3, 0));
[...]
msgsnd(mes_id, &message, sizeof(message.mvalue), 0);
```

For more details, look at the examples sections in the manuals of [msgrcv()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/msgrcv.3p.html) and [msgsnd()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgsnd.2.html).

**Calls to *sleep()***

Suppress the calls to *sleep()* during the server/client message exchange as they are synchronized: when one sends a message, the other waits for the reception. As you call *sleep(2)* in the client before the last "receive", when it wakes up, the server may have removed the message queue. For your example, just put a *sleep()* at the end of the server right before the destruction of the queue.